# How can I use Conditional formatting formula in the filter in the Gsheets to select 2 or more columns where cells that are not empty in both?

Tags: conditional-formatting, gs-conditional-formatting, google-sheets-query

so I have ABCDE columns and I want to see rows of the cells that are not empty in the C as well as D column. how do I do this? I know I can have one column do that but that way it would exclude the information in the other column.

Let me know if this doesnt make sense. I'll try to explain with an example

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused by your question as to whether you are trying to use Conditional Formatting or to create a filter.

If you are trying to use Conditional Formatting:

It sounds like you are trying to highlight a row if there is not a blank cell in column C and not a blank cell in column D of that row.

Create a Conditional Formatting rule with the following:

**Apply to Range** A1:E1000  <-- (or however many rows of data you have)

**Format cells if...** SELECT "Custom formula is"
=or(NOT(isblank($C1)),NOT(isblank($D1)))

**Formatting style**  Pick a color to highlight the row

This rule will highlight columns A-E for each row that has data in both column C and column D.

Comment: Hey, Sorry that my question didnt make sense, I want to create a filter and apply the edit 'filter with condition' option in the filter.

I need to see see data from two column C and D and not see the empty cells where both C and D cells from the same row are empty. If one of them is not empty then I need to be able to see it.